# Distinguish TCP server from client within netstat output

Tags: tcp, socket, netstat

I have a socket connection between a client process and a server process, both running on my machine. There are two entries shown for the connection as,

```
sudo netstat -ntp | grep 56442
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:56442         127.0.0.1:8002          CLOSE_WAIT  8276/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8002          127.0.0.1:56442         FIN_WAIT2   -
```

How can I figure out which is the server in this case?

I know that the TCP server is running on port `8002`, and a client connects to the listening server from port `56442`.

I am trying to figure out a way to distinguish between server and client, by looking at the `netstat` output entries.

And why doesn't the process id/description appear when the socket is in `FIN_WAIT2` state?

Comment: Check [this page](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ajmi), you'll get answer of your first part. By checking the status of your processes, i.e., which process is in which state? FIN_WAIT2 state can only be occupied by a server. Check image given in that link. Don't know exactly why the process description/pid is not showing.

Comment: If you look at the _whole_ output of `netstat -ntp` you will see that the first line tells you what each column represents. "Local Address" will be the address and port `listen()`ing (i.e the server bound on port 8002).

Comment: @shekharsuman: I believe that your link is misleading; you should look at [the RFP](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793) itself.  Once a TCP connection is established, it is symmetrical; anything that one side can do, the other can do.  The first socket to be closed (or shutdown) can and will go into `FIN-WAIT-1` and `FIN-WAIT-2` states; that can be either the client or the server side.

Comment: @Scott- I wasn't sure of it, that's why I didn't post that as an answer. But, I am not convinced by your reasoning either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `netstat -ntp` will only show client (nonlistening) sockets in the *Local address* column.

The **`-l`** flag should cause `netstat` to list server (listening) sockets only, and with **`-a`** you should get both and then you can differentiate based on *STATE*s.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the `netstat` without the `grep`,
you'll see that the column to the left of the center
has a heading like "Local Address"
and the column to the right of the center has a heading like "Foreign Address". 
The row that shows the local address that includes the server port number
is the server.

You may be able to get a better feel for this
if you start two client processes simultaneously and then run

```
sudo netstat -ntp | grep -E "Address|8002"
```

> And why doesn't the process id/description come,
>   when the socket is in `FIN_WAIT2` state?

Probably because the process has terminated;
after all, `FIN` stands for "finish" or "final". 
FIN packets and `FIN_` states are related to
shutting down (closing) a TCP connection,
which typically happens only when the processes are done with it
(and which happens automatically when one or both of the processes die). 
A socket can hang around in the system for a little while
after the process that had it open has gone away. 
Again, you can probably get a better feel for this by running `netstat`
when both processes are alive and well,
and then watching how it changes when they shut down.